# Docker - Multiple MySQL instances/containers running at the same time

Tags: mysql, containers, docker, instances

Is there a way to allow multiple MySQL instances/containers to run at the same time?

Comment: I know of no straight forward way to _disallow_ it. If you share a bit more detail on your use case and actual problem, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: this is a question for https://serverfault.com/. please ask there

Comment: Oh I think I can just run different containers from a MySQL base image and mount different ports to the host port 3306 :)